# NoClassDefFound in NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, android-notifications

The concept is to get notification at a specific time. Obviously, I did it, until I included the support for versions lower than `HoneyComb` and above it.

I have set min SDK version 8 and target SDK 17. As the class coding is much bigger, I am showing only the core area where the problem exists:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        Notification notification;
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, TaskDetails.class), 0);

        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

            notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    this);
            notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(text).setWhen(time)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text).build();

            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
        }
```

The problem is that,

- Some methods and constructors of Notifications class are deprecated.
- So, alternative to this, "developer.android.com" suggested to use
  `Notification.Builder`.
- But, the class `Notification.Builder` has methods that were included 
  in API level 11 (and thus showed errors in the lines `"Call requires API level 11 or more"`).
- So, it didn't allow me to run the project.
- After more googling, gave me the solution to use class
  `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

Finally, reached the stage where no errors were found, and I ran my project on my Sony Xperia Tipo Dual ST21i2...

Tragic ending: I get the following error log:

```
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at com.todotaskmanager.service.NotifyService.showNotification(NotifyService.java:99)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at com.todotaskmanager.service.NotifyService.onStartCommand(NotifyService.java:68)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
06-01 06:34:14.199: E/AndroidRuntime(4178):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The line number 99 is `NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(...`

Comment: Which SDK version you have installed on your IDE?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri I use the latest one, sdk version 22.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay... i solved my problem.

Right click on your project goto properties -> Java Build Path. Choose Order export tab. Make sure that Android Private Libraries is selected. If you have referenced library project. do the same for the library project also. Clean and Build.

Also goto android sdk manager and check that you have the android sdk build tools installed. This may not be necessary but make sure you have android build tools installed.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it was v4 android library checkbox :)

Comment: Thanks, in my case also it was v4 android library checkbox